# Какой движок для 3D моделей использует sketchfab.com?

Tags: веб-программирование, 3d, model

Есть такой сайт [sketchfab](http://sketchfab.com). На нем имеется множество 3D моделей с текстурами которые можно крутить. Хотелось бы узнать как реализована прогрузка моделей и текстур в браузере. Используется ли какой-то движок или же фреймворк? Если в нескольких словах то какие технологии здесь задействованы?

Answer (score 1):

Есть библиотека [Three](https://threejs.org/), на ней можно написать подобное.